# NSSearch Field Predicate Filter

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void) searchFieldChanged{

    MPVTModelList *list = [[MPVTModelList alloc] initWithClass:[MassPOAssignmentModel class]];

    [intersectionTableView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] byExtendingSelection:NO];

//    [searchIntersectionField setStringValue:[[[searchIntersectionField stringValue] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:kMPVTBlankString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:kMPVTBlankString]];

    [searchIntersectionField setStringValue:[searchIntersectionField stringValue]];
    NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init];

    if([[[searchIntersectionField cell]placeholderString] isEqualToString:@"Pricing Org"]){
       NSArray *tempArray=[[[searchIntersectionField stringValue] uppercaseString] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"tempArray %@",tempArray);

        NSString * str=[[searchIntersectionField stringValue] uppercaseString];
        NSLog(@"str is %@",str);


        for(id item in tempArray ){
            [intersectionTableView reloadData];
            array=[[[self intersectionList]entities]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mpoPricingOrg.stringValue contains[cd] %@",item]];
            NSLog(@" item is %@",item);
            NSLog(@"insie if arr %@",array);


            [list appendEntities:array];
            NSLog(@"hello %@",[[searchIntersectionField cell]placeholderString]);
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"inside else");
        array = [[self searchFieldController] updatePredicateWithFilterText:[searchIntersectionField stringValue] searchArray:[[self intersectionList] entities] searchTableView:intersectionTableView];
        NSLog(@"in side else array %@",array);
        [list appendEntities:array];
    }

    [self setIntersectionList:list];
    [list release];
    [intersectionTableView reloadData];
    [intersectionTableView deselectAll:nil];
    [super updatePlacard:intersectionTableView];

}
```

I have called this method in `-(void)controltextDidEditing`. But when I enter "China" the filter predicate works fine. But when I enter "China,Brazil" it only shows the record for China and not for Brazil. Please suggest a better way of doing it.